# Explaining this Bash Script

Tags: android, shell, command-line, adb

Alright i was flashing a debloater script on my **S6 EDGE**, but i was curious about how these commands acutally works so i decided to ask for some help...

> **update-script**

```
unmount("/system");
unmount("/data");
unmount("/preload");
ui_print(" ");

ui_print("Android 6.0 & 7.0 Debloat Script by Windforce0511");
ui_print("Script version: v1");
ui_print(" ");

ui_print("Mounting partitions: /system /data /cache");
run_program("/sbin/mount", "-t", "auto", "/system");
run_program("/sbin/mount", "-t", "auto", "/data");
run_program("/sbin/mount", "-t", "auto", "/cache");
ui_print("Partitions mounted");
ui_print(" ");

ui_print("Removing bloatware from /system/app");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/AASAservice");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/BluetoothMidiService");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/CloudGateway2017");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/GooglePrintRecommendationService");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/FlipboardBriefing");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/KnoxFolderContainer2");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/KnoxRemoteContentsProvider");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/Photos");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/SBrowser_5.0");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/ShareLink");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/SPrintSpooler7");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/Videos");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/ANTPlusPlugins");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/ANTPlusTest");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/ANTRadioService");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/AdvSoundDetector2015");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/AllShareCastPlayer");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/AllshareFileShare");
#run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/EasyOneHand3");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/FlipboardBriefingPanel");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/Music2");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/QuickConnect_40");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/BBCAgent");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/SBrowser_4_LATEST");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/ColorBlind_M");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/SecMemo3");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/app/SimpleSharing");
ui_print("Done!");
ui_print(" ");

ui_print("Removing bloatware from /system/priv-app");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/AutoPreconfig");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/AccessControl_N");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/AutomationTest_FB");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/CallLogBackup");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/AssistantMenu_N");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/AxelSpringer");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/BeaconManager");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/ColorBlind_N");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/EasySetup");
#run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/GalaxyApps_3xh");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/GalaxyAppsWidget_Phone");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/GameHome");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/GameTools");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/OneDrive_Samsung_v2");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/PreloadInstaller");
#run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SamsungAccount_Dream");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SamsungCloud");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SamsungMagnifier3");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SamsungPass_1.1");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SecEmail_N");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SecureFolderStub");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SFinder_v6");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SNS_v2_N");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SVoice");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SvoicePLM");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/VoiceNote_5.0");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/VoiceNote_4.0");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/Fmm");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/FotaAgent");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/GalaxyBeta");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/GearManager");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/GoogleFeedback");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/HwModuleTest");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/ImsLogger+");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/KLMSAgent");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/LiveBroadcast");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/MyPlaces_Hero");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/PhoneErrService");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/PowerPoint_SamsungStub");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/RNB");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/RNBShell");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/sCloudBackupAppMOSUpgrade");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SCloudService");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SKSMAgent");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SNS_v2");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SOAgent");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SPDClient");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SPPPushClient_Prod");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SVoiceLang_EnglishPack_GB_1.0");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SVoiceLang_EnglishPack_US_1.0");
run_program("/sbin/rm", "-rf", "system/priv-app/SVoiceLang_FrenchPack_1.0");
ui_print("Done!");
ui_print(" ");

ui_print("Cleaning Cache and Dalvik-cache");
delete_recursive("/cache");
delete_recursive("/data/dalvik-cache");

ui_print("Unmounting partitions: /system /data /cache");
unmount("/data");
unmount("/cache");
unmount("/system");
ui_print(" ");

ui_print("Enjoy smoothness and much better battery life! :)");
ui_print(" ");
ui_print(" ");

ui_print("You can easily edit script and add character ' # ' to exclude certain APP from deleting.");
ui_print(" ");

ui_print("############################################");
```

Here are the things that i don't understand:

1. sbin/rm
2. sbin/mount
3. t
4. auto

I've checked the sbin directory on my phone but there was no rm or mount files..
So please anyone explain to me in detail 'cause i'm a newbie in Bash Scripting.

Comment: `/sbin/rm` and `/sbin/mount`are the linux executables, which purpose you can easily find on the internet. `-t` and `-auto` are the parameters of those executables. What each of them does you also can find on the internet. As for `but there was no rm or mount files` - there *probably* was no those files because you checked when it was unmounted, or for some other reason (none of us could know why)

Comment: In the sbin folder all other files were showing except rm or mount. If it was not mounted then why these other files were showing.  Maybe even with rooted device we can't see them, or they are hidden in the system somewhere.

Comment: `or for some other reason (none of us could know why)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright I've figured this out.

The scripting language used is called [Edify](https://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Edify_script_language). While similar to bash, the format is different, but both call Linux programs to perform tasks.
You can read the manual (man) page for [rm](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html) and [mount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) if you want to. And for anyone who is looking for `rm` and `mount` files inside `sbin`, stop looking for it you won't find it, even as a `root user`

---

Typically, these days, in TWRP. The recovery will mount a busybox implementation which provides access to basic Linux like programs mounted in the sbin directory. You must reboot to recovery to have access to these.

Comment: 2 good answers!. Be sure to accept the answer that best solved  your problem and upvote any answers that helped your understanding. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I'm accepting my own answer but it says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

the things you don't understand  can be divide into  two command group,

1. rm group
   `/sbin/rm -fr` delete directory and files  silently
2. mount group
   `/sbin/mount -t auto` mount partitions under auto configured parameters, mostly related with  `mtab` and `fstab`

you can do more research on quoted terminology above

if you cant see the `rm` and `mount` file under `/sbin`, there are two explanation i can think of

1. only app with effective root privilege  can do that, and you are viewing in an app that does not holding root privilege when scanning `/sbin`.
   rooting device is by placing a special binary file `su` under special dir.
   app has to call `exec("su")` explicitly to start a process with root privilege
   so that it can delete system files, mount or umount partitions, etc.
2. you are viewing in a `chroot` environment, the real /sbin is outside the environment.
   which is less likely to happen on your phone,
   it is a way of relocating `/` directory for process(and its sub-process) .